# How to get a graph bar with two categorical variables

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have this graph in Stata 14:

[wrong chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vg4N.png)

built with this data:

[data columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vb8Q.png)

I used two commands to generate the last two variables to build the graph I want:

```
// Command 1
gen mayores_65=0 if Edad>=65 & ID !=.
replace mayores_65=1 if Edad<65
label values mayores_65 dSíNo
label define dSíNo 0 "No" 1 "Sí"
label values mayores_65 dSíNo

// Command 2
gen Estatus=0 if Nivel_social==0
replace Estatus=1 if Nivel_social==1
replace Estatus=2 if Nivel_social==2 | Nivel_social==3 | Nivel_social==4 | Nivel_social==5
```

And then I generate the graph (first image) with:

```
graph bar (percent), over(Estatus) over(mayores_65)
```

Is there any possibility to obtain this graph?

[expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EM0h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this sequence helpful:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

graph bar (percent) ,  over(rep78) over(foreign)

graph bar (percent) ,  over(rep78) over(foreign) asyvars
```